# Hibernate, SQL server and @SqlResultSetMapping with native query

Tags: sql, hibernate, sqlresultsetmapping

I'm working with a very old database and I've to retrieve some specific data.
I use sql server and hibernate. I've written a class named Language with a guid (id of a person) and a set known languages. I've to retrieve all languages known by each person in the db, but I don't know if I can fill the languages set with a specific native query.

```
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "queryLanguages",
      query = "SELECT c.GUIDPersona as guid, d.Caption as language" +
          " FROM " +
          "     Competenze c " +
          "         INNER JOIN " +
          "     DomainItemsCaption d " +
          "         ON (c.IdConoscenza = d.ItemID) " +
          " WHERE " +
          "     d.DomainName = 'Conoscenza' AND " +
          "     d.Caption LIKE 'Lingue ~ %'",
      resultSetMapping = "Languages"
    )

    @SqlResultSetMapping(
      name = "Languages",
      entities = {
        @EntityResult(
          entityClass = Language.class,
          fields = {
            @FieldResult(name="guid", column="guid"),
            @FieldResult(name="languages", column="language")
          }
        )
      }
    )

    public class Language {
      private String guid;
      private Set<String> languages;
      ...
    }
```

Can I fill the "languages" field with a specific native query retrieving all known languages for the person associated to the entity?

Comment: I also wanted to do a similar kind of thing. Please let me know whether the above worked for you?